# Trouble using push in stack

Tags: c, stack

I'm learning data structures and I have a problem pushing data into my stack. Even though I have used the same push function early in the program it doesn't seem to push characters. The program should transform infix expressions to postfix

When given the number "1+2" it should return "12+", however it only returns "12"
Thanks in advice

```
       bool revisar(char * inf, stack p){
            inicializa(&p);
            Nodo D;
            char pos[MAX];
            int i=0;
            int j=0;
            while(inf[i]!='\0')
            {//WHILE
                if(inf[i]>='0' && inf[i]<='9')
                {     
                    pos[j++]=inf[i++];     
                }
                if(inf[i]=='(')
                {     
                    D.caracter=inf[i++];
                    push(&p,D);    
                }
                if(inf[i]==')')
                {   

                    while(top(p).caracter!='(')
                    {
                        pos[j++]=pop(&p).caracter;                 
                    }
                    if(top(p).caracter=='(')
                        pop(&p);
                    i++;   
                }
                else
                {
                    if(inf[i]=='+'||inf[i]=='-'||inf[i]=='*'||inf[i]=='/')
                    {
                        if(empty(p)||top(p).caracter=='(')
                        {   
                            D.cara

cter=inf[i++];
                        push(&p,D);
                        if(empty(p));
                        printf("NNNNNNOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"); **Here it prints that the stack is still empty....
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(menorpre(top(p).caracter,inf[i]))
                        {
                            D.caracter=inf[i++];
                            push(&p,D); 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pos[j++]=pop(&p).caracter;
                            if(!empty(p))
                            {
                                if(top(p).caracter!='(')

                                pos[j++]=pop(&p).caracter;
                            }
                            else
                            {   
                                D.caracter=inf[i++];
                                push(&p,D);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        while(!empty(p)){
        printf("ddd");
        pos[j++]=pop(&p).caracter;  
        }   
        pos[j]='\0';

        printf("\n \n");
        printf("i=%d,j=%d",i,j);
        printf("LA CADENA EN POSFIJO ES: ");
        puts(pos); 
    }
```

My stack library

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include "pila.h"

void inicializa(stack *p ){
    *p = NULL;
}

bool empty(stack p){
    if (p==NULL){
    return true;
}
    else return false;      
}

int push(stack * p, Nodo n){
    stack nuevo = (stack)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    if(nuevo == NULL){
        return 300;
    }
    *nuevo = n;
    if(empty(*p)){
        nuevo->next = NULL;
        }
    else{
        nuevo->next = *p;
    *p = nuevo;
    }
    return 301;
}


Nodo pop(stack * p){
    Nodo copy = *(*p);
    free(*p);
    *p = copy.next;
    inicializa(&copy.next);
    return copy;
}

Nodo top(stack p){
    Nodo copy;
    copy = *p;
    copy.next = NULL;
    return copy;
}
```

The header file

```
struct nodo{
    char caracter;
    int numero;
    struct nodo * next;
};
typedef struct nodo Nodo;
typedef Nodo * stack;
void inicializa(stack *p);
bool empty(stack p);
Nodo top(stack p);
Nodo pop(stack *p);
int push(stack *p, Nodo n);
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information about what the program is supposed to do, so it's difficult to know what the intended legal input is.  Also, how do you determine if a particular node contains a character or a number?  I suggest creating functions specifically to allocate, duplicate, and free `nodo` variables.  That cleans up the look of code a lot, and you can write the allocate function to take initial value arguments, like a constructor in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer -- in this code:

```
int push(stack * p, Nodo n){
    stack nuevo = (stack)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    if(nuevo == NULL){
        return 300;
    }
    *nuevo = n;
    if(empty(*p)){
        nuevo->next = NULL;
        }
    else{
        nuevo->next = *p;
    *p = nuevo;
    }
    return 301;
}
```

The `*p = nuevo;` should come after the `else`, not inside it.  It applies regardless.  The longer answer:

There are several problems with your stack code, including mismanagement of malloc'd memory.  I suggest a simpler stack design, along the lines:

```
struct nodo {
    char caracter;
    struct nodo *next;
};

typedef struct nodo Nodo;
typedef Nodo *stack;

void inicializa(stack *p);
bool empty(stack p);
char top(stack p);
char pop(stack *p);
int push(stack *p, char c);

void inicializa(stack *p) {
    *p = NULL;
}

bool empty(stack p) {
    return (p == NULL);
}

int push(stack *p, char caracter) {
    Nodo *nuevo = malloc(sizeof(*nuevo));

    if (nuevo == NULL) {
        return 300;
    }

    nuevo->caracter = caracter;

    if (empty(*p)) {
        nuevo->next = NULL;
    } else {
        nuevo->next = *p;
    }

    *p = nuevo;

    return 301;
}

char pop(stack *p) {
    Nodo *copy = *p;

    *p = copy->next;

    char caracter = copy->caracter;

    free(copy);

    return caracter;
}

char top(stack p) {
    return p->caracter;
}
```

This requires a revision of `revisar()` along the lines:

```
void revisar(char *inf, stack p)
{
    char caracter;
    char pos[MAX];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    inicializa(&p);

    while (inf[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (inf[i] >= '0' && inf[i] <= '9')
        {     
            pos[j++] = inf[i++];     
        }
                else if(inf[i] == '(')
                {     
                      (void) push(&p, inf[i++]);    
                }
                else if (inf[i] == ')')
                {
            while (top(p) != '(')
            {
                pos[j++] = pop(&p);                 
            }

            if (top(p) == '(')
            {
                (void) pop(&p);
            }

            i++;   
        }
                else
        {
            if (inf[i] == '+' || inf[i] == '-' || inf[i] == '*' || inf[i] == '/')
            {
                if (empty(p) || top(p) == '(')
                {   
                    (void) push(&p, inf[i++]);

                    if (empty(p))
                    {
                        printf("NNNNNNOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO"); // Here it prints that the stack is still empty....
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (menorpre(top(p), inf[i]))
                    {
                        (void) push(&p, inf[i++]); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pos[j++] = pop(&p);

                        if (!empty(p))
                        {
                            if (top(p) != '(')
                            {
                                pos[j++] = pop(&p);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {   
                            (void) push(&p, inf[i++]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

        while (!empty(p))
    {
        pos[j++] = pop(&p);  
    }

    pos[j]='\0';

    printf("\n \n");
    printf("i=%d, j=%d", i, j);
    printf("LA CADENA EN POSFIJO ES: ");
    puts(pos); 
}
```

In my testing, I was able to get `revisar("1+2", p);` to produce:

```
% ./a.out
ddd

i=3, j=3LA CADENA EN POSFIJO ES: 12+
%
```

Which I'm guessing is what you're after.  If you have more questions about this, make sure to add the definition of `menorpre()` to your code above as it's the piece that's missing that can't be reconstructed.

Comment: Short question, how would you return the string to the main

Comment: @CrappyCoder, you can't just replace `puts(pos);` with `return(pos);` as the memory for `pos` disappears with the subroutine call.  The quick fix would be to do `return(strdup(pos));` with the understanding that the caller would need to `free(pos);` when finished with it.  Another approach would be to let the caller pass in (a pointer to) `pos` as an argument, having allocated more than enough space (and possibly also pass the size of `pos`).  Then the caller can allocate from the stack, or `malloc()` or whereever and knows how to properly dispose of it (if/when needed.)

Comment: It says [Warning] return makes integer from pointer without a cast, i'm trying to pass the value of pos to a calculator function to evaluate the posfix expression, thanks for all the help

Comment: @CrappyCoder, did you change the declared return type of the function when you changed what it returns?  If you went with the strdup approach, the function's return type changes to char *. The  Other than that, I can't debug code I can't see.